# Set Organization wide email as TO address for SingleEmailMessage

Tags: singleemailmessage, org-wide-email

I want to use an organization wide email address as both to and from address (to send notifications to an email alias).

Method `setOrgWideEmailAddressId(emailAddressId)` only sets from address. I can set it as 'To' address by using `setToAddresses(toAddresses)` with string address but it counts against email limits to external addresses which I would like to avoid.

Is there any way to use an org-wide email address as a 'To' address without hitting email limits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately not. The only valid targets for setTargetObjectId is a User, Lead, or Contact. You would need to have a user set up specifically for this purpose, rather than an org-wide email address. If you have an API Integration user (typical in larger organizations), you might set that user's email and use it as the target for sending emails to, or in smaller orgs, you might just use an admin user instead. Otherwise, you're going to have to accept that you'll be limited on your daily emails.